# Same Code Giving Different Output in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, printf, exc-bad-access

I am stumped by this. I am pasting the program below.

```
void printGrid(int n,char grid[n][n]){
    for(int i = 0; i<n ; i ++) {
        printf("\n%s",grid[i]);
    }
}

int main() {    
    char grid[6][6]= {"-----","-----","-----","-----","-----"};

    printGrid(5, grid);

    for(int i = 0; i<5 ; i ++) {
        printf("\n%s",grid[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-----
-
--
---
-----
-----
-----
-----
-----
```

Why does the same `for` loop produce different output outside and inside the function `printGrid`?

Comment: Keyword: two-dimensional arrays ain't double pointers.

Comment: Note, that `"-----\0"` is actually 7 bytes (`\0` is added automatically (silently) for each string literal). Also, the `grid` array is `6x6` and you're telling `printGrid`, that `grid` is `5x5`, which is completely different.

Comment: H2CO3 cud u elaborate ? Kiril yeah i got that i just put that there thinking abt smthing else .

Comment: @H2CO3 that must be key-phrase I think?

Comment: @eddardstark - regarding your edit - again, the initialization of `grid` is bad - you've missed the last element. And again - you're "lying" `printGrid`, that `grid` is `5x5`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You re using a VLA but the size does not match the dimensions of the array you passed in. When you have an array:

```
char a[m][n];
```

The char at `a[x][y]` is found essentially by `a + x*m + y`.  Moreover, the layout of the array you made in memory looks like this:

```
-----\0-----\0-----\0-----\0-----\0-----\0
```

But since your first dimension is 5 instead of 6, when you index each row you are hitting it like this:

```
-----\0-----\0-----\0-----\0-----\0-----\0
^     |    |     |     |     |     |
      ^    |     |     |     |     |
           ^     |     |     |     |
                 ^     |     |     |
                       ^     |     |
                             ^     |
                                   ^
```

(your loop doesn't actually print the last two). If you instead call it like:

```
printGrid(6, grid);
```

you will see the output is more what you expect because the strides line up.  The other loop should probably be using `6` as well.

Comment: thanks man ... i never realized dat d size we specify in the function prototype will affect hw its indexed . anyways this was a bug in the c template of the site hackerrank which hosts programming puzzles . They asked to fill in a function like some(int size,int array[size][size]) but else where in main it was declared of a different size and passed in . i never thought their code would have a bug and i wasted hours after this .. wat i pasted above is a reduced version . TL DR : ur explanation rocks !!!